# How can I use comma separated string from a column as value for MySQL IN statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table which I want to left join.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_1;
CREATE TABLE test_1 (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  description varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of test_1
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO test_1 VALUES ('1', 'Item A', 'Description for Item A');
INSERT INTO test_1 VALUES ('2', 'Item B', 'Description for Item B');
INSERT INTO test_1 VALUES ('3', 'Item C', 'Description for Item C');
INSERT INTO test_1 VALUES ('4', 'Item D', 'Description for Item D');
INSERT INTO test_1 VALUES ('5', 'Item E', 'Description for Item E');


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_2;
CREATE TABLE test_2 (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ids varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of test_2
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO test_2 VALUES ('1', '1,2,5');
```

I want to return the same result that (A) will give but from (B)

```
(A) SELECT t1.*, t2.id as control FROM test_1 t1 LEFT JOIN test_2 t2 ON t1.id IN (1,2,5);
(B) SELECT t1.*, t2.id as control FROM test_1 t1 LEFT JOIN test_2 t2 ON t1.id IN (t2.ids)
```

The problem is that MySQL IN expects an array while I have a string from t2.ids column. Is there any way out?

Comment: **Don't store csv data in database columns. That's really bad schema design, and this is just one reason why out of many.**

Comment: It's not really a CVS data rather some group of data that have reference in some other table

Comment: Why would it be so bad for your application's design to have a true M:N relationship table for Table2? As such: (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, fromID INT NOT NULL, toID INT NOT NULL) This would let you freely add any number of relationships, not have to look up one row to update a relationship set, and you can join normally and your in clause can be a simple select statement against Table2.

Comment: I clearly understand that all. But this is really a different case if I should show the full table design/structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all that have contributed. Nevertheless, I was able to find my solution with MySQL FIND_IN_SET

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.id as control FROM test_1 t1 LEFT JOIN test_2 t2 ON t1.id= FIND_IN_SET(t1.id, t2.ids);
```